# MSBuild 4 and MSDeploy command line

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I'm trying to automate deployment of a site. I started with this [article](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/web-packaging-creating-web-packages.html)

and everything works great from VS 2010. However, I'm having problems with the command line
I use this

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "d:\Projects\test.csproj" /T:Package /P:PackageLocation="d:\Package\packageTest.zip"
```

to create the package

and

```
d:\Projects\packageTest.deploy.cmd "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value=MSBuild/Test2" /y
```

to get to at least deploy correctly. 
However, it doesn't take any of the IIS options (the app pool is MSBuild instead of ASP.NET v2.0) and, as I said before, the IIS Web Application Name is wrong.
Shouldn't this information be taken from .csproj file?
All these settings are done for debug configuration and platform any cpu

Comment: I still don't know what platform msbuild takes, but when I set these changes for all platforms in VS 2010, worked fine.

Comment: Even without setting IS Web Application Name. This question should be closed

Answer (score 6):

You typically setup your application on the IIS first, with correct path, application pool and so forth. When setup you can use MSBuild to deploy into that application name like this:

```
msbuild <your_web_project_name>.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=bin /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<url_to_your_server>:8080/msdeploy.axd /p:username=<username> /p:password=<password> /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployIisAppPath=<your_site_name> /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

If you don't want to setup the site manually, you could run a power shell looking something like this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
New-Item iis:\Sites\<your_site_name> -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:<your_site_name>} -physicalPath c:\inetpub\wwwroot\<your_site_name>
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\<your_site_name>' ApplicationPool "ASP.NET v4.0"
```